# why this coding not work inside updatepanel?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Why this code doesn't work inside `UpdatePanel` controls I have in webform : four `CheckBoxe`s and one `TextBox`

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim str As String = Nothing
        Dim id As String = Nothing
        Dim ch As String = Nothing
        For Each ctrl As Control In UpdatePanel1.Controls

            If ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(CheckBox) Then
                Dim chk As CheckBox = ctrl
                If chk.Checked = True Then
                    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
                        TextBox1.Text = chk.ID
                    Else
                        Dim SearchString As String = chk.ID
                        id = TextBox1.Text
                        If id.Contains(SearchString) <> -1 Then
                            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "," + chk.ID
                        Else

                        End If

                    End If
                Else
                    Dim SearchString As String = chk.ID
                    id = TextBox1.Text
                    If id.Contains(SearchString) <> -1 Then

                    Else
                        id = RemoveSubString(id, chk.ID)
                        TextBox1.Text = id
                    End If

                End If

            End If
        Next
    End Sub



    Private Function RemoveSubString(ByVal stringvalue As String, ByVal stringremove As String) As String
        Dim pos As Integer = stringvalue.IndexOf(stringremove)
        If pos > 0 Then
            Return stringvalue.Remove(pos - 1, stringremove.Length + 1)
        ElseIf pos = 0 Then
            If stringvalue.Contains(",") <> -1 Then
                Return stringvalue.Remove(pos, stringremove.Length)
            Else
                Return stringvalue.Remove(pos, stringremove.Length + 1)
            End If

        End If
        Return stringvalue
    End Function
```

Coding was working fine outside the `UpdatePanel` ...but not working inside update panel ...what is wrong with it?

Comment: No need to shout, unless you are past your deadline. ALL CAPS is online shouting. DONT

Comment: @astander OP may not be aware of it! Better you could change it?

Comment: @Quintin Robinson has already done so.

Answer (score 0):

What's it not doing? Works for me when pasting your code. (Would comment above, but can't post pic.)

[image: pic]

Comment: Its not works when anyone checks on ckecjboxes its id could not be retrieve in textbox in checkbox checked state...

you need button also to did this ///

Comment: i want when user check on checkboxes inside update panel its value automaticcaly retrieve in textbox on when checkbox is check

Answer (score 0):

You should set your checkboxes' `autopostback` to `true`, and assign `oncheckedchanged` event like this (not on `page_load`):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

Protected Sub CheckBox_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    'logic here
    TextBox1.Text = CType(sender, CheckBox).ID
End Sub
```